# Error compiling implementation and header file

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl, header-files

I'm trying to add the definitions for my member functions in `game.h` but I'm getting compiler errors that say the void functions are previously defined. The same error are output from `game.h` and also from `game.cpp`. It's almost like the `pragma once` is not working?? Im getting an error in Rider also saying the same thing in the `game.cpp` file but only for void functions.

**game.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "SDL2/SDL.h"


class Game{
public:

    Game() {}
    ~Game() {}

    bool init(const char* title, int xPos, int yPos, int width,int height, int flags);



    void render(){};
    void update(){};
    void handleEvents(){};
    void clean(){};


    bool running() {return m_bRunning;}

private:

    SDL_Window* m_pWindow;
    SDL_Renderer* m_pRenderer;

    bool m_bRunning{};
};
```

**game.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "game.h"


bool Game::init(const char* title, int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height, int flags){

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0){
        std::cout << "SDL init success\n";

        m_pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(title, xPos, yPos, width, height, flags);

        if(m_pWindow != nullptr){
            std::cout << "window creation success\n";
            m_pRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(m_pWindow, -1, 0);

            if(m_pRenderer != nullptr){
                std::cout << "renderer creation success\n";
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(m_pRenderer,255,255,255,255);
            }
            else{
                std::cout << "renderer failed\n";
                return false;
            }
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "SDL init fail\n";
            return false;
        }

        std::cout << "Successful initialization\n";
        m_bRunning = true;
    }
}

void Game::render() {
    SDL_RenderClear(m_pRenderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(m_pRenderer);
}


void Game::handleEvents() {
    SDL_Event event;
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
        switch (event.type){
            case SDL_QUIT:
                m_bRunning = false;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

void Game::clean() {
    std::cout << "clenaing up\n";
    SDL_DestroyWindow(m_pWindow);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(m_pRenderer);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "game.h"

Game* game = 0;

int main(){
    game = new Game();
    game->init("Chapter 1", 100, 100, 640, 480, 0);

    while (game->running()){
        game->handleEvents();
        game->update();
        game->render();
    }

    game->clean();

    return 0;

}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(sdl2_demo VERSION 0.1.0)

add_executable(sdl2_demo ./src/main.cpp src/game.cpp src/game.h)

target_link_libraries(sdl2_demo SDL2)
```

**error**

```
====================[ Build | sdl2_demo | Debug ]===============================
/app/extra/clion/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/benmarr/repos/sld2_demo/cmake-build-debug --target sdl2_demo -j 12
[2/3] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/sdl2_demo.dir/src/game.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/sdl2_demo.dir/src/game.cpp.o 
/usr/bin/c++   -g -MD -MT CMakeFiles/sdl2_demo.dir/src/game.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/sdl2_demo.dir/src/game.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/sdl2_demo.dir/src/game.cpp.o -c /home/benmarr/repos/sld2_demo/src/game.cpp
/home/benmarr/repos/sld2_demo/src/game.cpp:39:6: error: redefinition of ‘void Game::render()’
   39 | void Game::render() {
      |      ^~~~
In file included from /home/benmarr/repos/sld2_demo/src/game.cpp:6:
/home/benmarr/repos/sld2_demo/src/game.h:20:10: note: ‘void Game::render()’ previously defined here
   20 |     void render(){};
      |          ^~~~~~
/home/benmarr/repos/sld2_demo/src/game.cpp:45:6: error: redefinition of ‘void Game::handleEvents()’
   45 | void Game::handleEvents() {
      |      ^~~~
In file included from /home/benmarr/repos/sld2_demo/src/game.cpp:6:
/home/benmarr/repos/sld2_demo/src/game.h:22:10: note: ‘void Game::handleEvents()’ previously defined here
   22 |     void handleEvents(){};
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/benmarr/repos/sld2_demo/src/game.cpp:58:6: error: redefinition of ‘void Game::clean()’
   58 | void Game::clean() {
      |      ^~~~
In file included from /home/benmarr/repos/sld2_demo/src/game.cpp:6:
/home/benmarr/repos/sld2_demo/src/game.h:23:10: note: ‘void Game::clean()’ previously defined here
   23 |     void clean(){};
      |          ^~~~~
/home/benmarr/repos/sld2_demo/src/game.cpp: In member function ‘bool Game::init(const char*, int, int, int, int, int)’:
/home/benmarr/repos/sld2_demo/src/game.cpp:37:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   37 | }
      | ^
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: They are already defined. Lines like `void render(){};` both declare and define the function. Attempting to define them again is an error

Comment: The error messages that your compiler gave you are very helpful.  You should learn how to read these. It tells you the exact problem about the multiple definitions and shows you the locations of both implementations. `void render(){};` counts as a definition of the function.

Comment: Side note: Be wary of the final diagnostic: *warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]*. It's only w a warning so the program will still compile and run, but if the program ever takes a path through the function where it doesn't return, and the warning suggests it's possible, [the results can be hard to predict](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and probably, but not always,  wrong.

Answer (score 7):

You have an implementation in your header for some functions (empty):

```
void handleEvents(){};
```

And then an implementation in your source.

```
void Game::handleEvents() {
    SDL_Event event;
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
        switch (event.type){
            case SDL_QUIT:
                m_bRunning = false;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Update the header to just be a declaration:

```
void handleEvents();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your game.h file, you're creating empty implementation of the class methods, however in your game.cpp file you are creating full implementations of the same class methods.

Transform from

```
    void render(){};
    void handleEvents(){};
    void clean(){};
```

To this

```
    void render();
    void handleEvents();
    void clean();
```

All you need is the decleration of the function in your header file, then you can define them in your .cpp file